# Jquery resize image with a heart beat effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Hello want to make a image with a heartbeat effect.
It has to resize a bit, let's say maximum 20 pixel bigger, and then goes to original size.
It will be like a heartbeat, 2 beats - original, 2 beats - original.

So far I found only this effect:

```
    (function pulse(back) {
    $('#seventyfive').animate(
        {
            'font-size': (back) ? '100px' : '140px',
            opacity: (back) ? 1 : 0.5
        }, 700, function(){pulse(!back)});
})(false);
```

Or you can check it out here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D3X7R/57/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/D3X7R/77/ check it out

Answer (score 11, accepted):

this will do

```
(function pulse(back) {
$('#seventyfive img').animate(
    {
        width: (back) ? $('#seventyfive img').width() + 20 : $('#seventyfive img').width() - 20            
    }, 700);
$('#seventyfive').animate(
    {          
        'font-size': (back) ? '100px' : '140px',
        opacity: (back) ? 1 : 0.5
    }, 700, function(){pulse(!back)});
})(false);
```

Comment: Hey, @Patrick ... is there a way to change a bit the effect... like: 2 quick pulses and then 2 seconds break, 2 quick pulses and then 2 seconds break

Answer (score 6):

I would do it like this simply using `.animate`

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/D3X7R/72/

```
function pulse() {
    $('#seventyfive').animate({
        width: 300, height: 300, // sets the base height and width
        opacity: 0.5
    }, 700, function() {
        $('#seventyfive').animate({
            width: 320, height: 320, // sets the alternative height and width
            opacity: 1
        }, 700, function() {
            pulse();
        });
    }); 
};

pulse();
```

Answer (score 5):

You wan't a real Beating Heart effect?
So what are you waiting for? check the following ;)

**HTML**

```
<img id="seventyfive" 
     src="http://upload7.ir/imgs/2014-02/60314995125165880641.png"/>
```

**CSS**

```
#seventyfive{
    position:absolute;
    font-size:100px;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

**JS**

```
var size = 150;
var s_size = 0.66 * size;
var m_size = 0.83 * size;
var s_resize = ( size - s_size )/2;
var m_resize = ( size - m_size )/2;
var image = $('#seventyfive').css('width',size);

var x = image.offset().left; 
var y = image.offset().top; 

function pulse() { 
    image.animate({ 
        width: s_size, top:x+s_resize,left:y+s_resize 
    }, 350, function() { 
        image.animate({ 
            width: size, top:x, left:y 
        }, 100, function() { 
            image.animate({ 
                width: m_size, top:x+m_resize, left:y+m_resize 
            }, 70 ,function(){ 
                image.animate({ 
                    width: size, top:x , left:y 
                }, 70, function() { 
                   pulse();  
                }); 
            });  
        }); 
    });  
}; 

pulse();
```

[Fiddle Demo HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsennazari/2bS4e/)

Comment: This seems like a real heart beat with double pulse!

Comment: I've been looking all over for the double pulse - this is the first one I found!  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**HTML**

```
<div><img id="seventyfive" src="http://winters.yorku.ca/wp-content/blogs.dir/271/files/2011/11/twitter-icon.png" /></div>
```

**JS**

```
(function pulse(back) {
    $('#seventyfive').animate(
        {
            'font-size': (back) ? '100px' : '140px',
            opacity: (back) ? 1 : 0.5,
            height: (back) ? "100%" : "50%",
            width: (back) ? "100%" : "50%",
            'margin-top': (back) ? "0" : "25%",
            'margin-left': (back) ? "0" : "25%"
        }, 700, function(){pulse(!back)});
})(false);
```

**CSS**

```
#seventyfive{
    position:absolute;
    font-size:100px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

[Fiddle Demo HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/D3X7R/73/)

Answer (score 2):

In CSS3:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/D3X7R/76/)

```
var timeoutThrottle,back = true;
$('#seventyfive').on('transitionend',function(e){
    clearTimeout(timeoutThrottle);
    timeoutThrottle = setTimeout(function(){ back = !back; pulse(back); },0);
});
var pulse = (function pulse(back) {
    $('#seventyfive').toggleClass('heartBeat', back);
    return pulse;
})(back);
```

Answer (score 0):

In this solution the number of beats is a parameter (reps):

```
 function pulse($cnt,time,reps){
    reps = reps || 2;
    (function beat(count) {
         $cnt.animate({
            opacity: (count<=0) ? 1 : 0.5
            'font-size': (count<=0) ? '100px' : '140px',
         }, time,
         count==0? undefined :
                   function(){ beat(count<0? -count-1 : -count+1); });
    })(reps+1);
 }
```